# Get role inheritance state for document library in SharePoint Online

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I work with SharePoint Online drives(document libraries) with Microsoft Graph API (`/drives` call). With this API I can download/upload files but cannot work with permissions.

That's not a problem - I can do it with SharePoint Online REST API (with calls `_api/web/GetListByTitle('Title')/hasuniqueroleassignments`).

The main problem here is matching drive from MS Graph API and a corresponding list from SharePoint REST API. For now I match by title but I have several examples, when `name` field in MS Graph API is equal to "OneDrive", but title in `List` entity is `Shared Pictures`.

Is there any way to match more precisely entities from Graph API and SharePoint REST API?

Answer (score 0):

The Drive Item object has a SharePointIds property that will provide the information necessary to call the SharePoint REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepointids?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

Use [List resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0), you could get list id.

Then use id to call rest api.

```
/_api/web/Lists(guid'54ca94c0-364e-4201-8fe7-a4c804769009')/hasuniqueroleassignments
```